# Monitoring Java Heap Space in Netbeans

Tags: grails, netbeans6.7

I want to monitor my Java Heap Space.

Since i got the infamous Java Heap Space i raised the heap space.

But i want to monitor how the need of space from my Application is.

Additional Info (not sure if it is needed):

-Using Netbeans for creating Webapps with Grails

-Application Server is Glassfish and Tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans has a built in [profiler](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html) that you can run your application with. You can monitor the heap usage and browse the heap to see what objects are using up the space.